# Script doing sed in a file and circle the output

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

I'm trying to make a script for the following redirect:

Day 1

```
Dobritoiu    - Palmar
Gae            - Icinga
Petrisor    - Backup
Popa        -
Pupaza        -
Vargatu        -
Vasuica        -
```

Day 2

```
Dobritoiu    - 
Gae            - Palmar
Petrisor    - Icinga
Popa        - Backup
Pupaza        -
Vargatu        -
Vasuica        -
```

And etc till we have a circle. The output will be redirect via email.
So far i'm here:

```
sed -e "1s/$/ Palmar/" -e "2s/$/ Icinga/" -e "3s/$/ Backup/" group_test | mail -s 'test' email_address
```

.
.
.

```
sed -e "7s/$/ Palmar/" -e "1s/$/ Icinga/" -e "2s/$/ Backup/" group_test | mail -s 'test' email_address
```

group_test contain my template:

```
Dobritoiu      - 
Gae            - 
Petrisor       - 
Popa           -
Pupaza         -
Vargatu        -
Vasuica        -
```

Also I need to use some conditions:

1 - we have 3 weeks: 
    first week the script need to run at 07:00 from Monday to Saturday
    second week the script need to run at 11:00 from Monday to Friday
    week three the script need to run at 15:00 from Monday to Friday
And this 3 weeks are in a circle also.

2 - I think I need to have a different file:

```
Dobritoiu      - work
Gae            - work
Petrisor       - work
Popa           - free
Pupaza         - work
Vargatu        - work
Vasuica        - work
```

or something like a calendar...in case of one of us if free in that day to be able to skip to the next person. Also would be nice if I can implement our monthly timesheet and / or the oncall days (oncall is only in week 2; 1 person per day) and etc :)

Do you have any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "circle the output", what does that mean?

Comment: I mean after the day 1 day 2 ... day 7 the script will repeat the order

Comment: I think you need a calendar app...

Comment: I like to try this way...